# Displaying data from Firebase Database into an html document

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display data from Firebase Database into an html document. Under you can see both my HTML and JavaScript file. I'm pretty new to Firebase, so I have most likely done a mistake. Appreciating all answers!

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<p id="profile"></p>

<table id="profiledetails-table">
    <tr id="tr">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)

    docRef.get().then(function(snapshot) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

            $('#profiledetails-table').append(doc.data);

        } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use an undefined variable (and your editor/IDE should have warned you): you're using `if (doc.exists)` but `doc` is not defined, hence `doc.exists` will always be undefined or you must have some "Cannot read property exists of undefined" kind of error in your devtools.

This is the way you might want to do it:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)

    docRef.get().then(function({ doc }) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

            $('#profiledetails-table').append(doc.data);

        } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    })
});
```

I don't really know jQuery so I can't be sure there is no bug in the way you append data to your table, so you might want to have a look at it if this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As @Camille mentioned, you need to use snapshot.exists and snapshot.data().